# Is "$id" class property name too short?

Tags: php, naming-conventions, phpmd

When used as property of an object, for example User::id or File::id, name "id" makes perfect sense in my opinion. However PHP Mess Detector complains:

> Avoid variables with short names like $id.

I understand, that $id as a local variable is not descriptive enough, but class or object name should provide sufficient context.

If there's a reason why "id" is too short, what's the proper way of naming object identifier variable and why?

Comment: It's just a suggestion - not a rule.

Comment: id alone is ambiguous even if you're using something like `User::id` so make it `userId`

Comment: PHPMD doesn't work with "exception", just suggestions and math (eg.: cyclomatic complexity)